# Run jquery function every 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I want to run a function every 15 seconds but my setInterval don't work and I don't know why... The function is called just once...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

param = new Object();
param['menu_hover_time'] = 5000;
    function hoverMenuAnimate(){

    if(param['menu_hover_flag']) 
    {

      $('.menu-item-423').delay(param['menu_hover_time']).queue(function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');

        $('.menu-item-3704').delay(param['menu_hover_time']).queue(function() {
          $(this).trigger('click');

          $('.menu-item-424').delay(param['menu_hover_time']).queue(function() {
            $(this).trigger('click');

            $('.menu-item-422').delay(param['menu_hover_time']).queue(function() {
              $(this).trigger('click');
            });

          });

        });        

      });
    }
  }

  setInterval(hoverMenuAnimate(),15000) 

});
```

Thanks you for you help.
Best regards,

**EDIT**

The problem was the .queue() :

```
/* Animated menu */
  function hoverMenuAnimate(){

    if(param['menu_hover_flag']) 
    {

      setTimeout(function(){
        if(!param['menu_hover_flag'])return;
        $('#menu-1 nav#site-navigation .menu-item-422').css('background', '#f0f2f5').children('a').css('color', '#204056');
        $('.menu-item-423').css('background', '#e5251e').children('a').css('color', '#fff');
        $('#submenu-container-1').html(($('.menu-item-423').children('ul.sub-menu').html()));
        $('#submenu-container-1').css('float', 'right').css('marginRight', '110px');

        setTimeout(function(){
        if(!param['menu_hover_flag'])return;
          $('#menu-1 nav#site-navigation .menu-item-423').css('background', '#f0f2f5').children('a').css('color', '#204056');
          $('.menu-item-3704').css('background', '#e5251e').children('a').css('color', '#fff');
          $('#submenu-container-1').html(($('.menu-item-3704').children('ul.sub-menu').html()));
          $('#submenu-container-1').css('float', 'right').css('marginRight', '110px');

          setTimeout(function(){
            if(!param['menu_hover_flag'])return;
            $('#menu-1 nav#site-navigation .menu-item-3704').css('background', '#f0f2f5').children('a').css('color', '#204056');
            $('.menu-item-424').css('background', '#e5251e').children('a').css('color', '#fff');
            $('#submenu-container-1').html(($('.menu-item-424').children('ul.sub-menu').html()));
            $('#submenu-container-1').css('float', 'right').css('marginRight', '110px');
            if(!param['menu_hover_flag']){return;}

            setTimeout(function(){
              if(!param['menu_hover_flag'])return;
              $('#menu-1 nav#site-navigation .menu-item-424').css('background', '#f0f2f5').children('a').css('color', '#204056');
              $('.menu-item-422').css('background', '#e5251e').children('a').css('color', '#fff');
              $('#submenu-container-1').html(($('.menu-item-422').children('ul.sub-menu').html()));
              $('#submenu-container-1').css('float', 'right').css('marginRight', '110px');

              }, param['menu_hover_time']);
            }, param['menu_hover_time']);
          }, param['menu_hover_time']);
        }, 1000);
    }
  }

  hoverMenuAnimate();

  setInterval(function(){ 
    hoverMenuAnimate();
  }, (4*param['menu_hover_time']));
```

Thanks you all for you help !

Comment: `setInterval(hoverMenuAnimate(),15000);`  basically says call setinterval with the *results* of the `hoverMenuAnimate` function every 15000 milliseconds (which is false since the function doesn't return anything).  What you mean is what @Stapal said below.  `setInterval(hoverMenuAnimate,15000);` which means call the `hoverMenuAnimate` function every 15000 milliseconds.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you're using `queue()` without triggering the next item in the queue. The callback to `queue()` is passed an argument, which is a function that should be invoked.

Comment: @Karl: That's not fully a duplicate. There are other problems with the code That would cause the interval to appear to fail.

Comment: @cookiemonster in the post, it clearly say *"setInterval don't work and I don't know why"* and *"The function is called just once..."* So his current problem is answered in the duplicated post. Once he solve that, he **may** have an other problem, I agree, but again, he **may** be able to debug it. If he can't, and if you look at the grey box, then he can ask an other question about the next problem.

Comment: Or he can edit the question so it ask the right thing, then ping me and I will gladly remove the mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setInterval` accept a function to execute after delay. When you use `()`, you are calling it. Just pass the function reference to `setInterval`.

Use

```
setInterval(hoverMenuAnimate,15000); //Notice removed () from here
```

Comment: Hello, sorry but the problem persist... I think "queue" is the problem...

Comment: @Dimi: Change the callback: `.queue(function(next){ $(this).trigger('click'); next(); })` Notice the `next` parameter and the `next();` invocation of that parameter.

Comment: ...also, in your demo, you have no `param['menu_hover_flag']` defined.